# Cant resize or make new partition

Tags: 14.04, gparted, disk, partitioning

I just install my first Ubuntu and now want to resize or make new partition, i try with gparted and usb, but they didnt help me. what to do?

[image]

Comment: To explain the other answers a little more, the key icon tells you that the partition is locked because it's mounted.

Comment: You are showing LVM, which is an advance partitioning system used for servers and if you want full drive encryption. If LVM part of another drive you must be careful as damaging it damages both drives. Gparted does not work on LVM, but does on the partition/container for the LVM only. But the LVM fully uses the physical partition. You have to use LVM tools, but can create partitions inside the LVM as that is an advantage of LVM. https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm

Comment: If you don't need a GUI, I'm pretty sure you can boot into /bin/bash and use a tool without a GUI like parted or fdisk to modify the partitions.

Answer (score 1):

Because of the choices that you made during the installation of Ubuntu, you can't use `gparted` to modify the partition structure. You need to use `LVM` utilities instead.

In `terminal` type `apropos lvm` and you'll see some of the CLI (command-line-interface) tools to use. Type `man tool_name`to get help on any specific tool. These can be quite terse and complicated to use.

Another way to manage LVM partitions is to use a graphic interface tool like `system-config-lvm`.

Here's the description:

System-config-lvm provides a graphical interface to the LVM tools (and related utilities, including fsck and resize2fs) which is good for non-emergency storage administration. It enables you to manage your logical volume and filesystem configuration with a few mouse clicks, and it prevents potentially-disasterous command-line mistakes such as reducing a logical volume size before reducing the filesystem contained within that volume.

To install system-config-lvm:

In `terminal`...

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install system-config-lvm
```

Then type `lvm` into the Unity dashboard search to start this tool.

To get more help on LVM, please see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify a mounted partition.

Burn a Ubuntu Live CD, or use a bootable Flash Drive to install GPARTED (sudo apt-get install gparted) to change your hard-disk  partition.

Comment: `gparted` won't work with LVM partitions.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot move, resize, or delete partitions while they are mounted.

At boot of your OS, the partition it's automatically mounted, so the GParted shipped with your distro cannot operate on your Ubuntu partition.

You can create a Gparted or Live bootable USB/CD or an Ubuntu Live USB/CD in order to operate on the drive with your OS installed.

Comment: `gparted` won't work with LVM partitions.